# Google Maps iOS SDK placesClient?.fetchPlace never gets response

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios, google-places

I've been trying this for a while and there is never a response back from Google. PlaceID is found using GMS Autocomplete. Code is pretty much copied and pasted from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/ios-sdk/place-details#get-place Anyone have any ideas?

```
        let placeID = placeIdString
        // Specify the place data types to return.
        let fields: GMSPlaceField = GMSPlaceField(rawValue: UInt(GMSPlaceField.name.rawValue) | UInt(GMSPlaceField.coordinate.rawValue) |
          UInt(GMSPlaceField.placeID.rawValue))

        placesClient?.fetchPlace(fromPlaceID: placeID, placeFields: fields, sessionToken: nil, callback: {
          (place: GMSPlace?, error: Error?) in
            print("bueller?")
            if let error = error {
              print("An error occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)")
              completion(nil)
            }
            if let place = place {
              //self.lblName?.text = place.name
              print("The selected coord is: \(place.name ?? "nada") \(place.coordinate.latitude) \(place.coordinate.longitude)")
              //coordFound = place.coordinate
              completion(place.coordinate)
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use shared instance for places client:

`private var placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()`